# Javascript comparing multiple arrays to get unique value across all

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array:

```
var array = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [2, 3],
    [3, 4],
    [3]
];
```

I'm trying to end up with a unique set of numbers from the arrays that appear in all arrays.

Therefore in this case returning

```
[3]
```

Any suggestions?

Many thanks :)

Comment: this looks like a homework question. Maybe you should give it a go and come back if you get stuck

Comment: There's actually a [meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309294/542251) about this type of question on the hot list right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the value of `array[0]` in a variable (let's call it `result`).

Loop from `array[1]` to the end.
In this loop, run through all the values of `result`. If the current value of `result` is not in `array[x]` remove this value from `result`.

At the end of the loop, `result` only contains the desired values.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the obvious "iterate over every array and find matching numbers in every other array" you could flatten (concat) the original array, sort it, then look for numbers that occur at four consecutive indexes. I'm not a fan of questions where OP doesn't show any effort, but this was quite fun, so here it goes

```
array.reduce(function(prev, cur){ 
   return prev.concat(cur); 
})
.sort()
.filter(function(item, i, arr){
   return arr[ i + array.length - 1 ] === item;
});
```

Or ES2015:

```
array.reduce((prev, cur)=>prev.concat(cur))
     .sort()
     .filter((i, idx, arr)=>(arr[idx+array.length-1]===i));
```

Comment: Thanks for helping @Pawel

Answer (score 0):

After learning i was using the wrong javascript method to remove from an array (pop) and some more tinkering. I got it working many thanks for those who responded.

```
var array = [
            [2, 3, 5, 1],
            [3, 4, 2, 1],
            [3, 2],
            [3, 4, 2, 5]
        ];

        var result = array[0]
        for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
                var arrayQuery = $.inArray(result[j], array[i]);
                if(arrayQuery == -1){
                    result.splice(j, 1)
                }
            };
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var array = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [2, 3],
    [3, 4],
    [3]
];

var arr = [];
for(var x in array){
  for(var y in array[x]){
    if(arr.indexOf(array[x][y]) === -1){
        arr.push(array[x][y]);
    }    
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

[Working Demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/2nggg63p/)